# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 doesn't work after applying impersonation in asp.net 4

Tags: impersonation, oledbconnection

In our application we allow user to upload excel file to server and import data from excel file to SQL.

We created one user and used that account for impersonation in application. We gave write and read excess to Upload folder to this user. Upload is working fine but at   oconn.Open(); it throws error

But if i use admin account for impersonation it's working fine

```
     using (OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelproperties.filePath + ";   Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"))
     {

          oconn.Open();  
     }
```

Comment: What error would that be?

Comment: There is unknown error. but I think the issue related to giving permission to this user.

Answer (score 0):

The account needs access to the TEMP directory
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/825738/system-data-oledb-oledbexception-error-when-you-run-an-asp-net-web-app